# Deserializing Repeating Dictionaries from JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary, json.net

I'm trying to de-serialize a large JSON file using JSON.net. I've been unable to de-serialize the nested dictionaries inside this file. The name of the object containing these dictionaries repeats thousands of times inside the file. The code I provided is a small, shortened version of the file I'm dealing with to show an example of these repeating nested dictionaries. I'm looking for a solution to de-serializing the contents of thousands of "image_uris" into classes I suppose, such that I can access the "small", "medium", and "large" keys and values from each "image_uris" object.

```
[
    {
        "object":"card",
        "id":"789",
        "image_uris":
        {
            "small":"https://img...98713",
            "medium":"https://img...89712",
            "large":"https://img...97123",
        }
    },
    {
        "object":"card",
        "id":"654",
        "image_uris":
        {
            "small":"https://img...43243",
            "medium":"https://img...26267",
            "large":"https://img...00812",
        }
    },
    {
        "object":"card",
        "id":"091",
        "image_uris":
        {
            "small":"https://img...98760",
            "medium":"https://img...92331",
            "large":"https://img...87690",
        }
    }
]
```

I've been working in the Unity Game Engine, with C#, with JSON.net. I have tried using http://json2csharp.com/ by feeding it the entire JSON file. It spits out ~1700 lines of code with implementation instructions commented at the top. I'm not sure how to access all the generated classes and data in those classes by following those instructions. Those instructions are as follows:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var scryfallDefaultCards = ScryfallDefaultCards.FromJson(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is but I just copy pasted your JSON snippet into the same site you went to and got this:

```
public class ImageUris
{
    public string small { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string large { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string @object { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public ImageUris image_uris { get; set; }
}
```

But your JSON is an array and you should just deserialize like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);
```

It should work the same using your larger JSON string